# Nice way to assign min max variables / deconstruct an array?

Tags: swift

I'm looking for an expression to assign the smallest and largest of 2 numbers to variables.

There are several approaches that work

```
let a = 2
let b = 1

let (min, max) = (min(a, b), max(a, b))
```

But I wanted something a bit more flexible, for example

```
let sorted = [a, b].sorted{$0 < $1}
let (min, max) = (sorted.first, sorted.last)
```

But it's 2 lines... I was looking for something like:

```
let (min, max) = [a, b].sorted{$0 < $1}
```

But that doesn't compile, I think because it's not possible to deconstruct arrays, at least in this way, and there doesn't seem to be a clean/meaningful way to convert it to a tuple.

What am I missing? I know there's somewhere an elegant expression for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d just do a variant of your (pre-edit) first one:

```
let (min,max) = a < b ? (a,b) : (b,a)
```

If you do this a lot, you could wrap this in a generic function to make it a bit neater:

```
func minmax<T: Comparable>(a: T, b: T) -> (T,T) {
    return a < b ? (a,b) : (b,a)
}
```

Which makes this quite nice and readable at the call site:

```
let (min,max) = minmax(a, b)
```

Comment: Ok, I agree that this is a bit better (first one/pre-edit). My (not really important) issue was that I have to write a and b multiple times, if this are long expressions (e.g. view.frame.width) It becomes a bit cluttered or I have to introduce local variables. A function is a good idea though right now I'm interested in exploring built in features... :P

Comment: Yeah some kind of array-to-tuple destructuring would be nice, but since tuples are fixed in size at compile time it wouldn’t be quite so straightforward.  But I’ve seen some nice examples of how you can add some kind of destructuring as an array extension – can’t find the one I’m thinking of right now but I’ll keep looking.